# GitHub App web application flow: What is the login parameter for when requesting the user identity?

Tags: github, github-api

I am building a GitHub app that requires user-to-server access tokens. I am following the [Web application flow](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#web-application-flow) so a user can sign in and my app gets the access token.

My question is about the `login` parameter in the `href` when requesting the [user's identity](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#1-request-a-users-github-identity):

> When your GitHub App specifies a login parameter, it prompts users with a specific account they can use for signing in and authorizing your app.

- What does specific account mean? Does it mean the currently logged in
  GitHub's user account?
- What is the point of this parameter?
- What is the difference between supplying the parameter and not
  supplying the parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `login` is a suggested github user. When I supplied a valid `login`, the authorization screen showed the suggestion on top when I was logged in with a different user account.

[image]

So a use case would be if you saved the user name already somewhere and want to remind the user to use that account.